# Opencart 2.3 Notice: Undefined property: Proxy:: function_name

Tags: php, codeigniter, opencart, vqmod, ocmod

I am working on Opencart 2.3, I have installed a new extension into the system and since then I am getting an error in the product description page in the front end:

> Undefined property: Proxy:: function_name**

The uploaded extension is in the admin section, the product description page was working fine before installing the new extension.

Note: The extension has vqmod file and modification folder has the files related to the extension.

Comment: You should add your code or at least name the extension if it is publicly available. However, if this question is not about *your* code, consider migrating it to [ServerFault @ SE](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: the name of the extension is booking and reservation, the extension is a paid one.

Comment: @Mike Your issue is fixed or not? How you fixed it? I am getting this Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getTemplate vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_model_checkout_order.php on line 660 Can you please guide me to fix this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this. 
My problem was the path to my extension was

extension\module\name_here

but since I just upgraded it from 1.5.6, which just had module\name_here. I forgot to change the class name to match the new path.

```
class Model**Extension**Modulename_here extends Model {
```

Extension word was missing.
The error is really obscure, and only upon finding it on github did it make sense what my mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue in the Live Server. But the thing is I had loaded the module and called it correctly. But still, it didn't do any favor for me.

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
$this->model_catalog_product->addmyproducts($myproducts);

class Model**Extension**Modulename_here extends Model {
```

The solution to getting around this problem was to figure out 
**How does the Architecture in OpenCart Framework works?**
**Follow the below solution:**

- Find under the Opencart directory for
  **/system/storage/modification/admin**.
   Here you'll be able to see the MVC directory
- Under the modification folder, you'll find all the codes written on to it
- You need to identify the calling part of the module in the model that has been defined or not?
- After identifying you'll come to see that function definition will not exist that's the reason!
- Further if you define the same function under the directory /system/storage/modification/admin/.../...you'll never see Undefined property: Proxy::module_name

### Update

Irrespective of the functions defined, if there are two functions with the same name called twice under a single file raises ambiguity in vqmod module

For Eg. Calling method `getWarehouseDetails()` if it lies under `index()` & another one in `warehousedetails()` in a single file with two different calls with two different file names while loading `$this->load->model(../..);` you'll get

> Notice: Undefined property: Proxy::getWarehouseDetails in
>   /var/www/html/bluemb/vqmod/vqcache/vq2system_storage_modification_system_engine_action.php
>   on line 51

In the below eg. getWarehouseDetails() called in index() & another one in warehousedetails()

```
$this->load->model('tool/upload');
$warehouse_details = $this->model_tool_upload->getWarehouseDetails($seller_id);

$this->load->model('catalog/information');
$this->data['warehouse_details'] = $this->model_catalog_information->getWarehouseDetails($seller['seller_id']);
```